# Selecting with PreparedStatements in clojure

Tags: mysql, clojure, prepared-statement

I am using Clojure.java.jdbc for database operations.

I want to select some rows using Clojure prepared statements.
I did it like this,

```
(jdbc/db-do-prepared db "select * from `users` where name='?'" ["hari"])
```

but throws an error like,

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs
```

So what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db-do-prepared` can only return an update count, and  is meant for doing prepared *mutations* like `update`. It doesn't accept queries that return a resultset, like `select`.

In `[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]`, the latest version, `query` is used for queries that return a resultset. For prepared values, quoting within the query is not necessary. Also, in the new version, you don't need a vector with values.

```
(jdbc/query db
            ["select * from users where name=? and surname=?" "hari" "krishnan"])
```